# How can I change a table td width using CSS in Spiceworks?

Tags: css, spiceworks

I’m trying to make a small change on a CSS for [Spiceworks](http://community.spiceworks.com/help/Spiceworks_Plugin_API).

This is the line that I want to change:

```
<td class="body-id cell-id" style="width: 12%; "></td>
```

Now this code:

```
SPICEWORKS.utils.addStyle('body{background-color:blue}');
```

changes the bg color to whatever I want. I think I can also use the `SPICEWORKS.utils.addStyle` to change a width of a table. What I don’t know is how can I say to the program that I want to change that specific `<td>`’s width?

P.S. I’m just a trainee so I’m not a pro in programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Spicework’s documentation](http://community.spiceworks.com/help/Spiceworks_Plugin_API#Utils), `addStyle` adds a CSS block to the `<head>` of the HTML page.

Because your `<td>` has its width defined in its `style` attribute, that width will actually override whatever you add via `addStyle`, unless (I think) you add `!important` to the style you add.

Could you try this?

```
SPICEWORKS.utils.addStyle('td.body-id.cell-id{width:100px !important;}');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use height/width property to change respective attributes of table/th/td etc.

. [Check w3schools for more info](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_table.asp)

Comment: Right, but it looks like the OP is using a server-side framework called Spiceworks.